# How would one select words in a string separated by commas in a MySQL field?

Tags: mysql, string, select, field

I'd like to take data from a field which is a string of words separated by commas and save each of those words to a variable. After which, I'd like to take the stored words and use them to retrieve information.

An example of this would be a field containing the information: "Bob,Sue,Adam,Tim,Hank" My goal is to select each name, using the commas to detect each different name, and save each name to a variable or, more efficiently, an array, then use a "for" command or similar to display relevant info about each person.

I'm using MySQLi commands, which I have been told are poorly documented; however, that is what my book instructed me to use.

Comment: A field should never contain "Bob,Sue,Adam,Tim,Hank". This should be 5 rows in a child table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `explode` function the other answers suggest will work fine, but it would be more elegant if you stored these names separately in a second table.

So, where you now have:

- `main`: `id`, `names`

I suggest:

- `main`: `id`
- `names`: `main_id`, `name`

You can then retrieve the names belonging to one row with a query such as:

```
SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = $id
```

To add a name belonging to a certain id, use:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE names (main_id, name) VALUES ($id, "$newname")
```

Comment: Ok. I apologize for my confusion. I have to create a working friends list. A user would visit a profile and click "add." This would add that clicking users name to the clickee's "friends" field with a comma separator. Would your method work with something such as that?

Comment: The separate tables approach would make your use-case easier. You just add a name to the names table (see expanded answer), whereas you would now have to retrieve the string, add a new comma-separated name, then replace the string in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I'll attempt your method. I've done HTML and CSS before but PHP and MySQL are two different animals.

Comment: By the way, if this is a table of people who can be friends with each other, proper database design dictates you store a persons id (probably an integer) in the friend field rather than his/her name. Using the id, you can always find the name back, but using only the name, it's hard to find the other info. If not impossible: two people can have the same name!

Answer (score 4):

You can use **find_in_set** in MySQL:

assume mysql field **"username"** has these values : **"Bob,Sue,Adam,Tim,Hank"**

```
$name="bob";
```

QUERY is

```
  select * from TABLE_NAME where FIND_IN_SET('$name', username);
```

Comment: That's cool! :-) I didn't know about this function. Even so, I believe a different table design would be more robust in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

1. select the field
2. $names = explode(',', $thefield);

You now have an array of the values

Answer (score 0):

`$arrayList = explode(',', "Bob,Sue,Adam,Tim,Hank");`

checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

You want to [EXPLODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) !

For example:

```
$persons= explode(",", "Bob,Sue,Adam,Tim,Hank");
```